# How to Hash String using SHA-1 with key?

Tags: java, android, security, hash, sha1

The time I used to develop applications on iPhone I was converting String to SHA1 with two combination:

- Data
- Key

Now I am developing an Android application and I did not any example for how to calculate SHA1 With key.

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

---

*[The code that I currently  use]*

```
private void convertStringToSHA1()
{
        String sTimeStamp  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS").format(new java.util.Date());
        String sStringToHash = String.format("%1$s\n%2$s", "Username",sTimeStamp);

        MessageDigest cript = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        cript.reset();

        cript.update(sStringToHash.getBytes("utf-8"));
        sStringToHash = new BigInteger(1, cript.digest()).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: What code did you use for that conversion?

Comment: SHA-1 with key .. is HMAC? what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @ thejh i am updating the answer right a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
private String sha1(String s, String keyString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(key);

byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));

return new String( Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

}
```

[SecretKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html) docs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but Base64.encodeBase64 is imported from android.util.Base64 or org.kobjects.base64? thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to let you know the API android.util.Base64 does not have the method you mentioned i used : android.util.Base64.encode(bytes, 0)

Comment: In my example this is imported from org.apache.commons.codec.binary and you can download it from http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using apache commons codec library:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='commons-codec', module='commons-codec', version='1.10')
)

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils

HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(key.bytes, message.bytes)
```